# inline knitr code that isn't a simple number

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

It is easy enough to do something like `\Sexpr{1 + 1}`. But how can I do `\Sexpr{mymatrix}` with `mymatrix` being a matrix object in R workspace? More generally, how can I print object that is more complex than just a number using inline code chunk?

Comment: Use string processing functions to turn your complex objects into a character string. BTW, this is not a question specific to LaTeX, so someone may have to move it to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Yihui I am not sure I understand how to turn a matrix into a string while preserving its block form. Could you tell me the name of the "string processing function"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question in the comment: there is no single name. I said functions, and I mean string manipulation functions like `paste()`, `substr()`, and so on. You may take a look at the packages for generating tables, and try `capture.output()`, then `paste()`. But I doubt if it is worth it -- why not using a code chunk? For example,

```
<<results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
xtable(mymatrix)
@

<<results='asis'>>=
library(knitr)
kable(mymatrix)
@
```

You can certainly make it in the inline code if you do not mind the long R expression, e.g. `\Sexpr{paste(capture.output(kable(mymatrix)), collapse='\n')}`.